# retriving multi line text data in a div from mysql database in php , entered by textarea

Tags: php

i want to retrieve a paragraph from MySQL data base in Ampps server  i wrote code as

```
    <?php                
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql"); mysql_select_db("employ");
            $query="select 'db_post_contant' from blog where id=6";
            $run1=mysql_query($query);                  
              if(!$run1){
                echo"oops".mysql_error();
              }
              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run1))                  
              {                         
                 $show=$row['db_post_contant'];
    ?>
                 <div > <?php echo"".$show ?> </div> 
    <?php 
              }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really explain anything. Is there any more detail you can add?

Comment: And the problem is...?!

Comment: Remove the quotes around `db_post_contant` on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query: 
 `$query="select 'db_post_contant' from blog where id=6";` 
 To:

```
$query="select db_post_contant from blog where id=6";
```

You cannot use quotes >`'`< around your table's name.

Comment: thanks every one this was helpful

Comment: @Maahi If it was helped u to solve the problem plz accept this as the answer.